# Custom Texonomy not showing under the custom post type admin menu

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

Hi guys i have created the custom post and custom texonomy for that custom post type but dont know why the texonomy not showing under admin menu bar please look into the code .veirfy is my custom post type .

```
function pluginprefix_setup_post_taxonomy()
{
            define( 'TLC_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
            define( 'TLC_PLUGIN_FULL_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

            // PCI DSS certificates
            $labels_taxonomy = array(
                    'name'                => 'Lead Assessors',
                    'singular_name'       => 'Lead Assessor',
                    'menu_name'           => 'Lead Assessor',
                    'all_items'           => 'All Lead Assessors',
                    'parent_item'           => 'Parent type',
                    'view_item'           => 'View Lead Assessor',
                    'add_new_item'        => 'Add Lead Assessor',
                    'add_new'             => 'Add New Lead Assessor',
                    'show_in_menu'        => 'Lead Assessor',
                    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Lead Assessor',
                    'update_item'         => 'Update Lead Assessor',
                    'search_items'        => 'Search Lead Assessor',
                    'not_found'           => 'Lead Assessors',
                    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
                    
            );


            $args_taxonomy = array(
                'hierarchical'=>true,
                    'labels'              => $labels_taxonomy,
                    'query_var'           => true,
                    'show_ui'             => true,
                    // 'show_admin_column'   => true,   
                     'public'            => true,
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                    'rewrite'   =>  array('slug' =>'lead_assessor'),    

            );

            // Registering your Custom taxonomy Type
            register_taxonomy( 'lead_assessor', 'verify', $args_taxonomy );

          // added in v3.0
          flush_rewrite_rules(); 

}
add_action( 'init', 'pluginprefix_setup_post_taxonomy' );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your post type name and taxonomy name is same, so please check.

Or

You can use below code to create post type and taxonomy.

```
/**
* Register a custom post type called "LA Posts".
*
* @see get_post_type_labels() for label keys.
*/
function cptui_register_my_cpts() {
    
    /**
    * Post Type: LA Posts.
    */

     $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "LA Posts" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "LA Post" ),
    );

     $args = array(
        "label" => __( "LA Posts" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "la_posts", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt" ),
    );

     register_post_type( "la_posts", $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts' );

function cptui_register_my_taxes() {


    /**
    * Taxonomy: Lead Assessors.
    */

    $labels_taxonomy = array(
        'name'                => 'Lead Assessors',
        'singular_name'       => 'Lead Assessor',
        'menu_name'           => 'Lead Assessor',
        'all_items'           => 'All Lead Assessors',
        'parent_item'         => 'Parent type',
        'view_item'           => 'View Lead Assessor',
        'add_new_item'        => 'Add Lead Assessor',
        'add_new'             => 'Add New Lead Assessor',
        'show_in_menu'        => 'Lead Assessor',
        'edit_item'           => 'Edit Lead Assessor',
        'update_item'         => 'Update Lead Assessor',
        'search_items'        => 'Search Lead Assessor',
        'not_found'           => 'Lead Assessors',
        'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
    );

    $args_taxonomy = array(
        'hierarchical'        =>true,
        'labels'              => $labels_taxonomy,
        'query_var'           => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'rewrite'             =>  array('slug' =>'lead_assessor'),
    );

    register_taxonomy( "lead_assessor", array( "la_posts" ), $args_taxonomy );

 }

 add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes' );
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but there is some other issue in my code thats by that was not worked but now its working fine :-)